# Create a blank workbook which is not saved

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to open a workbook in separate instance. Currently, this workbook is saved on the desktop. I would want to open a new workbook which is not saved or located anywhere on my system. Below is the current code which I have. Please advise.

```
Sub New_Excel()
  'Create a Microsoft Excel instance via code 
  'using late binding. (No references required)
  Dim xlApp As Object
  Dim wbExcel As Object

  'Create a new instance of Excel
  Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

  'Open workbook, or you may place here the 
  'complete name and path of the file you want 
  'to open upon the creation of the new instance
  Set wbExcel = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PRASHPRA\Desktop\Book.xls") 

  'Set the instance of Excel visible. (It's been hiding until now)
  xlApp.Visible = True

  'Release the workbook and application objects to free up memory
  Set wbExcel = Nothing
  Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to properly format your code; it makes it much easier to read. You can format it by pasting it, selecting it all, and then clicking the `{}` toolbar button or pressing Ctrl+K, or just indent it yourself by four or more spaces. You can preview it right below the text area where you're typing it in a WYSIWYG view that lets you see it before you post. If you need more formatting help, you can click the orange `?` button that appears above the top right corner of the text area. If we can read your code, you have a better chance of getting helo. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a new blank workbook, stop trying to open an existing one. Just change the line

```
Set wbExcel = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PRASHPRA\Desktop\Book.xls")
```

to

```
'Add a new, empty workbook
Set wbExcel = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
```

For more information, see [Creating a New Workbook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221273%28v=office.11%29.aspx) (the link is for Excel 2003, because it's the first one I found via Google, but it still applies, and if you want a more recent link you can probably find it the same way I did).